# Urllib2.urlopen python chinese in windows

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I'm making a little scrip in python. The objective is to make a request to a page that returns a Json file and work with the information. The problem is that I need to work with chinese words in the urls. When I make the request with (for example):

```
f = urllib2.urlopen("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=江苏省苏州市中国新加坡工业园区独墅湖科教创新区仁爱路111号&sensor=false")
```

In ubuntu I don't have problems and all is great, and give me the crrect json file. But when I try in Windows the resquest fails (said me that the url didn't exist).
There is a problem with chinese caracters in windows with urllib2?

The version of windows is 7, ubuntu 12.4. And I'm using python 2.7.

Thanks!

Marcos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should urlencode the query:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen

params = dict(address=u"我不知道中国人。", sensor="false")
query = urlencode([(k, v.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(v, unicode) else v)
                   for k, v in params.items()])
r = urlopen("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?" + query)
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!I tried the way you said before, but I still having the same problem. When I tested in Ubuntu the request give me the json file, but in windows said me that tha I had Zero results. And I'm using the same direction in chinnese to test.

Comment: @user3162595: make sure that the encoding declaration at the top of the module is correct: `print(params)` should show expected Unicode codepoints in the address (it must be the same output as on Linux (ignoring the order of parameters)).

Comment: I have the encoding declaration at the top. For example when I use this address value  u'中国江苏常州市武进区政平乡武进市禹城村' in the dict, and I print params give me this output {'sensor': 'false', 'address': '\xd6\xd0\xb9\xfa\xbd\xad\xcb\xd5\xb3\xa3\xd6\xdd
\xca\xd0\xce\xe4\xbd\xf8\xc7\xf8\xd5\xfe\xc6\xbd\xcf\xe7\xce\xe4\xbd\xf8\xca\xd0\xd3\xed\xb3\xc7\xb4\xe5\n'} in windows and in linux. But the result of the requests is different, in one I have the json file correctly and in windows is empty.

Comment: @user3162595: you might have forgot `u''` prefix. `address` should be Unicode string: `{'sensor': 'false', 'address': u'\u4e2d\u56fd...'}`

Comment: The script, takes a file that had a lot of chinesse directions that I saved in a list. So the value of the address key of the dict are the different directions that are in the list. I use the unicode function instead the u'' to transform the differents directions, and I stil having the problem.

Comment: @user3162595: to limit the scope of character encoding issues, `address` should be a Unicode string. If the source for addresses is an external file then you must know its character encoding (to be able to convert its content to Unicode text). If you don't know how to read a file and get a Unicode string; [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: When I read the part of the code where I was opening the file, I realized that I was using the common _open_ instead _codecs.open_. Thanks for all!